# Spie? Cryptic crossword clue

Tags: cryptic-clues, english

Cryptic crossword type clue

> Spie? (5,4)

This is meant to be a clue that could appear in a cryptic crossword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure this is intended to be:

> **MINCE PIES** (the Christmas delicacy)

Since:

> 'SPIE' is an **anagram** of 'PIES', and 'mince' could reasonably be used as an anagram indicator in this way. Hence 'SPIE' is one way that you could *mince PIES*...

Comment: It strikes me that this is more an 'inverted' cryptic clue of sorts, since the answer we are trying to deduce is pretty much some wordplay that could be used as a clue in itself.

Comment: A bit like the common "gegs"...

Comment: Great job, yes like 'gegs' @Stevo